# Need a regular expression to count only alphabets without white spaces between the sentence?

Tags: regex

I need to set  validation for number of alphabets in the text box without including white space can anyone suggest me with a regular expression

Comment: example would be better. And don't forget to show your attempts.

Comment: why a regular expression?

Comment: Also, please define your problem more precisely - what should happen if there is anything besides "alphabets" and whitespace in your textbox? And what exactly do you mean by "alphabet"? ASCII letters? Unicode letters?

Comment: /^[a-z]{0,10}$/ I just tried out this regex but it is accepting white space as a character I need to set limit only for alphabets and not spaces between them

Comment: What system? .Net, Java, Javascript, ...? The regex syntax can differ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but assuming you want to allow only letters and whitespace in your textbox, and the total number of letters must not exceed 10, then use

```
^\s*(?:[a-z]\s*){0,10}$
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bX2qH0/1).

**Explanation:**

```
^       # Start of string
\s*     # Optional whitespace
(?:     # Start of non-capturing group:
 [a-z]  # Match a single letter (don't forget the /i option if so desired)
 \s*    # Optional whitespace
){0,10} # between 0 and 10 times
$       # End of string
```

Comment: Thank you so much Working perfect

Answer (score 0):

Simple and sweet answer :) . (assuming s is the string).

```
System.out.println(s.split("\\s+").length);
```

this will printout the number of all the words(including if sentence contains numbers)

a quick way of gettin the total number of Alphabet here is a quick and dirty way.(doesn't use Reg Ex)

```
int counter=0;
for(Char c : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
  if(c=<'z' && c=>'a') counter++;
} 
System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: This would return `2` for `"abc def"`, not `6`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker oh sorry I thought you want the total number of words

Comment: @TimPietzcker I've updated my answer. hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply got my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'mlsqkf qsq merzo';
var n = str.replace(/[^a-z]/gi,'').length;
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e8y2na1s/1/)

Comment: What about uppercase letters?